# Unable to connect Linphone with FreePBX environment

Tags: asterisk, sip, linphone, sip-server, freepbx

**Problem**

I recently installed a FreePBX server(includes Asterix). I want to try and make few test phonecalls before proceeding the development of an application. I use the Linphone linux application to test this. Unfortunately a problem arises:   When connecting with Linphone to the FreePBX server the server becomes unreachable somethimes. As well as the admin panel at 192.168.178.20

- How can I fix this issue?
- And what is causing this?

**The ip configuration of the FreePBX server.**
[image: ifconfig]

**Linphone connecting to the FreePBX server (1000 user is registered in FreePBX as an extension)**
[image]

**Log from the moment I was connecting with Linphone to the FreePBX server**
[image: freepbx log]
**Server becoming unreachable**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Turns out fail2ban banned my IP adress due to too many failed logins.
- I cleared the ban list and this solved the issue. Also described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286119/delete-all-fail2ban-bans-in-ubuntu-linux